# UnhandledPromiseRejection when running NestJS jest tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I'm getting the following error when trying to run my unit tests:

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "TypeError: sapHeader.isDeleted is not a function".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

The thing is, I'm using a global `ExceptionsFilters` (exactly as it is on [NestJS Doc](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#throwing-standard-exceptions)), so I shouldn't need to manually place try catches all over my application, should I?
I'm entirely new on Nest, so I'm not sure what information I need to share.

Comment: In your test, do you bind the exception filter, or do you already have the filter bound via `APP_FILTER` or a `@UseFilters()` decorator?

Comment: I don't! My test is only testing my methods, should I bind it in there? If so, how do I do it?

Also... I was actually using the `app.useGlobalFilters(...........)` on my `main` file, should I use APP_FILTER?

Comment: @RinnieR do you know that the `main.ts` isn't loaded in tests, right? I mean, if you're relying on `bootstrap` configs, then make sure your tests are loading them as well.

Comment: Update: I just tried using APP_FILTER on my service module and it's still the same

Comment: @MicaelLevi I didn't... I actually didn't, but I tried using APP_FILTER on my module and it's still not working, I might be a bit dumb...

Comment: is that exception filter a [catch everything filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#catch-everything) one?

Comment: @MicaelLevi Yes, that's the one!

Comment: Are you only doing unit testing?

Comment: make sure you didn't miss any `await` (ie., leaving [floating promises](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md))

Comment: @JayMcDoniel For this specific case, yes! The error only occur when running my unit tests

Comment: @MicaelLevi I'll take a look and keep you updated, but I'm pretty sure I am not :(

Comment: Filters and other enhancers won't run during unit tests